# Gradually introducing Angular 2 in my ExpressionEngine websites

Tags: angular, expressionengine

I'd like to integrate user specific functionality from ExpressionEngine into my new Angular 2 app. Here's the background:

*Background*

I'm fairly new in the field of SPA but I've decided to move on with Angular (Angular 4) with my ExpressionEngine websites. As I can't simply totally replace the whole website (they are pretty complex), I'm working on migration strategy.

- Phase 1 is introducing new sections created with Angular like
  /newsection. In this phase, the only thing the user experiences is a
  fast reply and a basic responsive design.
- In Phase 2 we'll be replacing sections with Angular
- In Phase 3 we'll be replacing forms with Angular
- In Phase 4 introduce truly new components on our pages, making use of other kinds of storage like FireBase.

It's quite an exciting project!

The first thing I'd like to do it create a service layer on the backend, responding JSON objects, which can be intepreted by Angular. I've got this working right now in basic.

**Question**

The next thing I'd like to to is to get user specific information of the logged in user. Therefore, I'll need to know if the user is logged in.

1. How to login to a ExpressionEngine 2 website from an Angular App (with, let's say username/password).
2. How to retrieve information in an session in a secure way (site already works with htpps).

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same but I am still on Angular 1..

I accomplished this using "ng-init"..

To get the logged in user ID, I added this line in my EE template:

```
<ng-view ng-init="id = '{member_id}''"></ng-view>
```

This effectively injects the user ID into your controller / $scope as a variable 'id' IF the user is logged in and if they are not logged in the value will be null.